# Rspec Selecting option from react drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

[image: Attached is the CSS for the drop down]

I am new for rspec and ruby on rails. I would like to select one of the `options` shown in the attached image.

Can anyone suggest a simple way to click on the option? 
This is what I have tried

```
el = find("#menu-campaign_type_id")
        el2 =find("ul")
```

and I tried to find option inside `el2` but I am not able to find it. 
Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it will work on an `ul` tag but you should try using [capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara) with rspec, then you could do things like this:

```
within :css, '#menu-campaign_type_id' do
  select 'Awareness'
end
```

a simpler option would be

```
page.find('#menu-campaign_type_id > ul > option:first').select_option
```

Comment: 1. Unable to find visible option  within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="ul" path="/HTML/BODY[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[3]/UL[1]">

Comment: Failure/Error: page.find('#menu-campaign_type_id > ul > option:first').select_option
     
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError:
       invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: If you could share a JsFiddle of the code it will be easier to help. It fails in the first case because the element is not visible. Try leveraging Capybaras actions to make the element visible and then try selecting it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with `capybara` test cases. In `capybara` with `selenium web driver`.

But before that, you need to correct your drop-down code, there is an option inside `ul` tag, but it should be a `select` tag.

**drop-down example**

```
<div class="test">
   <select>
     <option value="op1">option1</option>
     <option value="op2">option2</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

You can achieve this by executing the `javascript`

```
    page.execute_script <<-JAVASCRIPT
       $("div.test select").val("op2");
    JAVASCRIPT
```

you can also try this

```
select 'option2', from: 'test', visible: false
```

hope it will help you to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
find("ul.MuiList-root").find(:option, Awareness).select_option
```